# "Call to undefined function oci_connect()" error on Mac

Tags: php, oracle

I am developing a website that connects to an Oracle Database with php. In order to achieve this, I have tried adding an oci_connect() extension to php.ini file stored in MAMP in order to run it with php. I have tried everything in the php.ini: added the extensions, uncommented some of the OCI8 commands but nothing worked.

I have been trying to solve this problem for a couple of weeks but every time I try doing something, nothing works out. If there are any Mac users here who were able to solve this problem, I will be very pleased if you could help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: well, you restartet apache after your changes in php.ini ?

Comment: @FatFreddy yup, I did multiple times. But the oci_connect() still does not seem to work.